# C# DataGridView Disable sort icon from the column header

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview, icons

I have a Winforms DataGridView with few columns which can be sorted and few which couldn't be.
For columns which I don't want my gridview to be sorted I have set

`dgvConnections.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;` in

`dgvConnections_ColumnHeaderMouseClick` event handler but I am unable to get rid of the the sort icon from the column header, as its presence could cause confusion to the user.

So kindly suggest me a way to get rid of the sorting icon from the column which cannot be sorted. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove sorting glyph in datagridview without removing Sorting facility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912382/how-to-remove-sorting-glyph-in-datagridview-without-removing-sorting-facility)

Comment: Are you setting the sort mode as Automatic anywhere in your code?

Comment: @KarthikAMR yes! I am. But that is in a method which is required for initial sorting of the gridview.

Comment: You might be calling that particular method after setting the sortmode as NotSortable. And the value is overriden. Can you check the execution order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are not maintaining the correct execution order. The code you wrote will do the work

```
dgvConnections.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```

but make sure you are calling it after initializing the DataGridView.

If you want it for specific columns like you mentioned in your question, you need to find the index and set the sortmode.

Comment: I think you we're right. I just added a condition for the columns I needed to get rid of the icon like below. and it worked! Thanks!
if (mSortColumn == 0 || mSortColumn == 5)
{
     dgvConnections.Columns[mSortColumn].SortMode = 
     DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
    return;
}